# Collect value from textfield in HTML and insert to database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple form in HTML with 2 input textfield, : name & age , and a submit button

I want after user click submit button name & age will be insert to table 'User' of models class

Can you teach me how to do that ? thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models:

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

template

```
    <form method="post" action="url"> 
    <input type="text" name="user_name">
    <input type"number" name"age">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
from app.models import *
def viewname(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance_user = user()
        instance_user.name = request.POST['user_name']
        instance_user.age = request.POST['age']
        instance_user.save()
        return HttpResponse('register done')
```

Comment: oh god, you save my life, tks bro